# Put H4 and 1st line of P on the same horizontal line, but the 2nd line of P should be vertically aligned with the 1st line of P?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to create a CSS style sheet for a stage play wherein the Character (H4) appears on the same horizontal line as the 1st line of the Dialogue (paragraph). At the same time, I want it so that when the Dialogue wraps, the beginning of the 2nd line of the Dialogue will be vertically aligned with the beginning of the 1st line of the Dialogue, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89i51.png).

I've managed to put the Character and the 1st line of Dialogue on the same horizontal line using `display: inline` for both and set `margin-left: 30px` for the Dialogue so as to create a good amount of horizontal space between the Character and the Dialogue. So that's great. Problem is, the 2nd line of the Dialogue goes way to the left and gets vertically aligned with the Character instead of with the 1st line of the Dialogue, as you'll see if you run my code below.

Now I tried deleting `display: inline` for both and setting the Dialogue to say, `margin-left: 150px` which fixes the problem -- the 2nd line of my Dialogue is now vertically aligned with the 1st line of my Dialogue. But then the 1st line of my Dialogue is no longer horizontally aligned with my Character.

It seems I can only either:

1. Horizontally align the 1st line of the Dialogue with the Character, or
2. Vertically align the 2nd line of the Dialogue with the 1st line of the Dialogue

But not both.

I'm new to CSS and I've scoured the internet but I can't find any solution to this. Is there a way to do both?

Is there anything I can add or remove from my CSS style sheet (not HTML) below that would allow me to do this?

```css
body {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 1in;
    margin-bottom: 1in;
    margin-left: 1in;
    margin-right: 1in;
    background-color: white;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    cursor: text;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

h1 {    /* Act */
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {    /* Scene */
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {    /* Stage Directions */
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

p + h3::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    block-size: 12px;
}

h4 {    /* Character */
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

h4::after {
    content: ":";
}

h4 + p { /* Dialogue */
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
}

h4 + p::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    block-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>ACT 1</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>ACT 1</h1>

<h1>Scene 1</h1>

<h3>These are the stage directions.</h3>

<h4>CHARACTER 1</h4>

<p>This is dialogue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<h4>CHARACTER 2</h4>

<p>This is also dialogue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>

<h3>Here are more stage directions.</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you've not chosen to use two divs, side by side ? One for character and one for the dialogue? You could display them table cell side by side on desktop, and then block on mobile responsively?

Comment: To answer both Qs, I've chosen not to use divs + I don't want to modify the HTML because I don't know how to mess around with HTML yet. I just started learning CSS yesterday haha. Also, I'm working with a writing app that uses Markdown on the front end, so I was hoping to just edit the CSS once in the back end so I can export docs in different styles without having to go in and add HTML code to the front end every time. But if that's really the only way to do it (combine Markdown and HTML) I guess I can give that a whirl.

Comment: If you think combining Markdown with HTML is the way to go, can you please show me how to add HTML divs or flexboxes to my Markdown syntax that will solve the problem? I can probably share my Markdown code for this if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution — and I want to share the code here for those who may also need it. Special thanks to u/sheriffderek from r/css for helping me figure it out.

```
h4 {    /* Character */
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h4 + p { /* Dialogue */
    padding-left: 100px;
}

h4::after {
    content: ":";
}
```

Comment: For other users to better understand your question and answer, please remove code that isn't relevant to your specific problem. While the CSS you provided displays the HTML as described, there are multiple problems with it that you should keep in mind. Your code will only work as long as the text of the h4 element stays the same length, as the paragraph has a fixed padding value. And on larger screens, your paragraph will be displayed in one line. You could consider adding max-length to limit the width of the paragraph.